# Mocking a static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, easymock

Below is the method i want to test. I am using TestNG framework for unit testing.

```
class Random{

    List<String> namesOfLinks;

    public List<String> methodIwantToTest(List<String> cktNames) {
            Map<String, Graph> maps =   DataBaseReader.getGraphs(cktNames);
            for (Entry<String, Graph> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
                graphList.add(entry.getValue().getName());
            }
    }

    return namesOfLinks;
}
```

I am writing the test cases for the method "methodIwantToTest" in the above class. I can provide some dummy cktNames and get the method to execute like below.

```
@Test (dataProvider = "dp")
public void test_methodIwantToTest(List<String> cktNames, List<String> expectedLinkNames){
    Random rm = new Random();
    List<String> actual = rm.methodIwantToTest(cktNames);
    Assert.assertEquals(actual,expectedLinkNames);
}
```

Now comes the problem. When the actual method is executing when i invoke it on the 'rm' reference, it has a static method call to another API. It has to return something in order for my "method" to work. I searched the internet and found "easymock" as a solution. But i am unable to use "easyMock" to mock the static method (DataBaseReader.getGraphs()). I have to mock that method so that it returns a map of the defined type. Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks !!

Other questions deal with how to test static methods. But mine is about mocking a static method while testing a instance method.

Comment: You can not mock a static method using easymock as well. You need to use powerMock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to do mock static methods directly. See https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Adapter pattern in combination with the Dependency Injection technique. Create an interface that contains all the methods you want to mock:

```
public interface IDatabase {
    Map<String, Graph> getGraphs(List<String> names);
}
```

Obviously, `Database` doesn't implement the interface you just invented (and the method is `static` anyway), but you can create an adapter class:

```
public class DataBaseReaderAdapter implements IDatabase {
    public Map<String, Graph> getGraphs(List<String> names) {
        return DataBaseReader.getGraphs(names);
    }
}
```

Take an instance of this class as a constructor parameter in the class you want to test:

```
public class Random {
    private readonly IDatabase _database;

    public Random(IDatabase database) {
        _database = database;
    }
}
```

and when you want to call the method:

```
Map<String, Graph> maps = _database.getGraphs(cktNames);
```

In your test, use any mocking framework to create a mock of `IDatabase`, and pass that mock to `Random`.

While this technique might seem pretty involved at first, it tends to lead to better designs in which the dependencies of a class are more visible and everything becomes easier to test.